# How to set store trigger for computed fields in Odoo 8?

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-8, odoo-8

I started using the new API of Odoo v8.0 but I cannot find useful information about store trigger in computed fields like this (for v7.0 and v6.1): [Store Parameter in Odoo v6](https://doc.odoo.com/v6.0/developer/2_5_Objects_Fields_Methods/field_type.html/#store-parameter)

In Odoo v8.0, I tried to use the same syntax of v7.0 but I couldn't get it to work because the JSON response cannot be returned back to the web client:

`<function _store_trigger> is not JSON serializable.`

I read then that store parameter had been converted to Boolean only field (no dict for triggers): [Odoo store function: JSON not serializable](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/4628)

So how can I set trigger to store values in database for computed (and related) fields? I want to make filters and groups mainly for them so `search function` won't be useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In V8, you can use any fields as computed fields. In V8 store is a parameter which is a boolean and by default it is **false**.

If you set explicitly "store=True", the dependent field you mentioned in **@api.depends('name')**, will acts as a triggering field.

You can specify, the other object field as a triggering field which will be must in accounting module like **@api.depends('other_object.field_name')**

```
upper = fields.Char(compute='_compute_upper', store=True)

@api.depends('name')
def _compute_upper(self):
    for rec in self:
        self.upper = self.name.upper() if self.name else False
```

If it "false", then the value is not stored in database and will be computed everytime.

```
upper = fields.Char(compute='_compute_upper')
```

Comment: so `store=True` will update the value every time it changes? what about related fields?

Comment: after some attempts and tests. I see that `api.depends` makes `store=True` triggered whenever the field changes.